# close skype port

Tags: skype

I don't trust skype but as most of my friends use it I'm stuck with it. I read on some posts that skype doesn't require an opened listening port in order to function properly. When I do sudo netstat -tulpn while skype is on I get

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:16464           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4874/skype
```

That is by the way the only listening port opened as I closed other things like samba and cups which I don't need. So my question is how can I close this port and will skype still be able to work if I close it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fuser` command

```
sudo fuser 4875/tcp -k
```

`fuser` will list all process listening on that port

`-k` to kill it